# Screenshots from PDF without creating a new file

Tags: preview, copy-paste

I have a document given as a PDF and would like to copy parts from it into Powerpoint. For example, an equation.

I use Preview's "Take a screenshot" function but this always generates a new Preview file with the selection. On this new file, I do a <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, and I have the image on my slide. I then have to delete the screenshot file.

What is an efficient way to select a certain portion of my PDF and copy it without generating a new file?

Comment: Can't you just select part of the PDF using the cursor and copy the selection and then just paste it into Powerpoint or Keynote. Works for me.

Comment: @jmh when I do that, it doesn't copy it correctly. Latex equations get converted into text whereas I want the original latex equation in my slide

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: I'm running 10.15.4.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re happy with a screenshot, there’s a screenshot-to-clipboard function built into macOS.

Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>. (Try doing that with one hand! :-) )

Comment: It's a good suggestion and will work for many but it unfortunately loses vector graphics properties of the PDF. When I zoom in and out of the selected content, I'd like it to stay sharp.